# Compiling OpenJDK 7 without X

Tags: linux, java, xorg, openjdk

I am trying to compile OpenJDK 7 on a headless RHEL server. I have no desire to install a bunch of miscellaneous X dependencies just to build it.

Is there any way to compile OpenJDK 7 without Swing/AWT support (and hence, without the need to link against /usr/lib{arch}/X11 at build-time?

Comment: You might have more luck at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RHEL, but usually their is an OpenJDK `*-headless` package in distributions that doesn't include GUI components, and normally no dependencies to X11 packages.

For instance debian [provide one](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openjdk-7-jre-headless) package and ArchLinux [too](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jre7-openjdk-headless/)

Comment: Correct, RHEL/CentOS/Fedora do not provide an analogue to those.

Comment: So, maybe looking at the ArchLinux [PKGBUILD script](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/java7-openjdk#n126) that generates the package can give you some hints.

Comment: Oh, thanks - I was looking at the Debian sources and it is U-G-L-Y

Comment: But after a quick look at the PKGBUILD, I am not sure this will help because I suspect that they build java with the GUI, and then just copy what is needed into the `-headless` one.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right, but this does get me a little down the path. I really feel like there have to be compile-time options floating around somewhere to do it but Oracle's stupid build infrastructure is nigh-impossible to grok.

Comment: An option like [this one](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#BUILD_HEADLESS_ONLY)? ;)

Comment: Well I was all excited about that option for a second, but then I found this: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2012-March/005710.html

Comment: And what about the idea to compile it with GUI support into a VM with the same architecture/OS, then copying the build folder to the server, and doing the `make install` here? The GUI will not work because the dynamic libraries aren't present, but you don't care. I haven't try this before so no idea if that can work, even theoricaly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8580/discussion-between-streakycobra-and-javanix)

Comment: There is now a package for java8: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless. Just for Java8, that is